# My Cordova plugin doesn't work in Monaca Debugger

Tags: html, cordova, monaca

I installed my own Cordova plugin into Monaca IDE.
When I run my app on Android Monaca Debugger (version 3.1.1) i get the following error message:

```
Call to undefined function
```

Comment: Is it possible to share your plugin? It seems like your plugin is not recognized in Monaca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Test third party cordova plugin, you need to build your custom debugger.
Open project in Monaca IDE and follow guide provided in following link to build project specific Monaca debugger, this debugger will include your custom cordova plugin for testing:

http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/en/manual/debugger/installation/debugger_android/#high